# How do you identify record pattern sequences in records using TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

This is a fairly new exercise for me but I need to find a way to identify pattern sequences within a table.
So for example, lets say I have a simple table that resembles the following:

[image]

Now what I would like to do is identify and group all the records which have the sequenced pattern of values 5, 9 and 6 presenting them in a query. How would you accomplish this task using T-SQL?

The results should look like this:

[image]

I've looked for some potential examples of how this might be accomplished but couldn't find anything that really helps.

Comment: Can you add a little text about the pattern  - how big it can be?

Comment: So you would have a pattern provided like `declare @Pattern as table ( Seq Int, Val Int ); insert into @Pattern ( Seq, Val ) values ( 1, 5 ), ( 2, 9 ), ( 3, 6 );`? Looks like a join with some fancy Row_Number matching, grouping and counts. A weird variant "gaps and islands" problem at that point.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov The pattern will never be more than 3 sequential numbers. In this case 5,9 and 6. But ideally, the solution should be able to accomodate a larger sequence if necessary with some modifications. The value is of type integer. Hopefully, I've interpreted your question properly. If not, please let me know

Comment: @HABO Yes, the table would be exactly as you've described and I have considered and explored the possibility of implementing the ROW_NUMBER function but I can't figure a way to identify the pattern that way. I've also thought of using a CTE in combination with the ROW_NUMBER function but still no go

Comment: Pretty clear, @Mark. I suppose that, but I want to be sure. Also is the KEY column is sequential?

Comment: I also think in that direction @HABO. To me this looks the obvious solution.

Comment: The key column is sequential as HABO has identified in his example of the layout

Comment: Start with `MyTable as MT left outer join @Pattern as P on P.Val = MT.Val`. Throw in a column to mark the start of a match: `case when P.Seq = 1 then 1 else 0 end as StartMatch`. Then search for [`gaps and islands`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) and see what you can sort out. We're here for backup.

Comment: Are values within a pattern guaranteed to be unique, i.e. a pattern can't have `42` appear twice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following query wrapped in a `CTE` in order to assign sequence numbers to the values contained in your sequence:

```
;WITH Seq AS (
    SELECT v, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY k) AS rn
    FROM (VALUES(1, 5), (2, 9), (3, 6)) x(k,v)
)
```

**Output:**

```
v   rn
-------
5   1
9   2
6   3
```

Using the above `CTE` you can identify islands, i.e. slices of sequential rows containing the whole of the sequence:

```
;WITH Seq AS (
    SELECT v, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY k) AS rn
    FROM (VALUES(1, 5), (2, 9), (3, 6)) x(k,v)
), Grp AS (
SELECT [Key], [Value], 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Key]) - rn AS grp            
FROM mytable AS m
LEFT JOIN Seq AS s ON m.Value = s.v
)
SELECT *
FROM Grp
```

**Output:**

```
    Key Value   grp
   -----------------
    1   5       0
    2   9       0
    3   6       0
    6   5       3
    7   9       3
    8   6       3
```

`grp` field helps you identify exactly these islands.

All you need to do now is to just filter out partial groups:

```
;WITH Seq AS (
    SELECT v, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY k) AS rn
    FROM (VALUES(1, 5), (2, 9), (3, 6)) x(k,v)
), Grp AS (
SELECT [Key], [Value], 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Key]) - rn AS grp            
FROM mytable AS m
LEFT JOIN Seq AS s ON m.Value = s.v
)
SELECT g1.[Key], g1.[Value]
FROM Grp AS g1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT grp
   FROM Grp
   GROUP BY grp
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 ) AS g2
ON g1.grp = g2.grp
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0adc5/3)

**Note:** The initial version of this answer used an `INNER JOIN` to `Seq`. This won't work if table contains values like `5, 42, 9, 6`, as `42` will be filtered out by the `INNER JOIN` and this sequence falsely identified as a valid one. Credit goes to @HABO for this edit.

Comment: Won't your first `inner join` drop any `mytable` values that don't match the pattern at all, effectively ignoring unmatched values rather than failing the pattern match?

Comment: @HABO Yes, the first `INNER JOIN` does exactly that, i.e. it filters out any unmatched values, like `8`, `3`.

Comment: If you use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `Seq` when forming `Grp` then you will have extra rows in an island if, for example, `mytable` contained 5, 42, 9, 6. The final check of the `COUNT` would toss out that group as unmatched.

Comment: @HABO Ok, now I see what you mean. Good catch! Actually I initally used a `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE` for `rn` but then dropped it for reasons of efficiency.

Comment: This fails as soon as the pattern includes the same numbers (eg. pattern is 7,3,3)

Comment: It gets caught up on this line LEFT JOIN Seq AS s ON m.Value = s.v, as when there are multiple matches on the pattern table it returns them all

Answer (score 1):

Not very optimized, but I think propper answer:

```
CREATE TABLE pattern (
    rowID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    rowValue INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO pattern (rowValue) VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO pattern (rowValue) VALUES (9);
INSERT INTO pattern (rowValue) VALUES (6);

SELECT * FROM pattern;

SELECT Trg.* FROM Keys Trg 
INNER JOIN pattern Pt ON (Trg.fValue = Pt.rowValue) 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT K.fKey - P.rowID AS X, COUNT(*) AS Xc FROM Keys K 
        LEFT JOIN pattern P ON (K.fValue = P.rowValue) 
    WHERE 
        (P.rowID IS NOT NULL) 
    GROUP BY K.fKey - P.rowID 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pattern)
) Z ON (Trg.fKey - Pt.rowID = Z.X);
```

I use a table for pattern joining it to the main table. I calculate difference between the `Key` and pattern `Key` and I show only that rows which difference is matching (and rows count for the difference matching rows inside pattern table).

Comment: I am going to opt for the 1st answer, I believe the 2nd answer may be a very valid solution as well but in terms of a very simplistic and elegant approach (especially for me) Giorgos solution seems what I am looking for. Bogdan, I will give you a vote for the usefulness of your answer though. Thanks!

Comment: 10x @Mark. I agree with you that answer 1 is much better (I voted it :)).