# Identifying Sequence Start and Ends in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has data arranged in a way that looks like this:

```
ID |  BOUNDARY  | TIMESTAMP
1  |  NULL      | 2016-01-01 00:20:00
2  |  A         | 2016-01-01 00:20:10
3  |  A         | 2016-01-01 00:20:14
4  |  A         | 2016-01-01 00:20:22
5  | NULL       | 2016-01-01 00:20:38
6  |  A         | 2016-01-01 00:20:45
7  |  B         | 2016-01-01 00:21:02
8  |  B         | 2016-01-01 00:21:12
9  |  A         | 2016-01-01 00:21:16
10 |  A         | 2016-01-01 00:21:22
11 |  C         | 2016-01-01 00:21:30
12 |  A         | 2016-01-01 00:21:35
13 |  A         | 2016-01-01 00:21:40
14 |  A         | 2016-01-01 00:21:46
15 |  A         | 2016-01-01 00:21:50
```

What I would like to do is find an efficient way to flag the ID and timestamps for the start and end of a sequence in SQL Server 2014.  A segment would be when a boundary is not null and repeats for at least two consecutive times. For example, the first segment would be from IDs 2-4 the second segment would be IDs 7-8, third would be 9-10.

The approach I tried first was to create two columns, a "startflag" col and an "endflag" column.  I create an update query that correctly flags the start and end, but I'd like to create a view where I can see it as one record, like below:

```
BOUNDARY | START ID | END ID  
A        |   2      |  4
B        |   7      |  8
A        |   9      |  10
A        |   12     |  15
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31704558/3585278

Comment: Why is Boundary = "C" not included in the final answer? because there are not two records?

Comment: Because there needed to be at least 2 instances in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but this works:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [TIMESTAMP]),
            RN2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BOUNDARY ORDER BY [TIMESTAMP])
    FROM #YourTable
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            RN1-RN2 RN3,
            COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY RN1-RN2) N
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT  BOUNDARY,
        MIN(ID) [START ID],
        MAX(ID) [END ID]
FROM CTE2
WHERE N > 1
AND BOUNDARY IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY BOUNDARY, RN3
ORDER BY [START ID];
```

If we use this sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable
    ([ID] int, [BOUNDARY] varchar(4), [TIMESTAMP] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO #YourTable
    ([ID], [BOUNDARY], [TIMESTAMP])
VALUES
    (1, NULL, '2016-01-01 00:20:00'),
    (2, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:20:10'),
    (3, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:20:14'),
    (4, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:20:22'),
    (5, NULL, '2016-01-01 00:20:38'),
    (6, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:20:45'),
    (7, 'B', '2016-01-01 00:21:02'),
    (8, 'B', '2016-01-01 00:21:12'),
    (9, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:21:16'),
    (10, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:21:22'),
    (11, 'C', '2016-01-01 00:21:30'),
    (12, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:21:35'),
    (13, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:21:40'),
    (14, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:21:46'),
    (15, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:21:50')
;
```

The results are:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦════════╗
║ BOUNDARY ║ START ID ║ END ID ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬════════╣
║ A        ║        2 ║      4 ║
║ B        ║        7 ║      8 ║
║ A        ║        9 ║     10 ║
║ A        ║       12 ║     15 ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: +1 but I think the order by TIMESTAMP should really be ID especially if TIMESTAMPs could be out of order e.g. change record 3 to be 1 day later and you get a funky result.

Comment: @Lamak:  I did a test on a small subset of the data and it seems to work!  My table has thousands of rows of data, so let me run through the whole set and verify.

Comment: @user3150002 no problem. Take your time and test as needed

Comment: This worked for me on a similar problem, I had a solution using `OUTER APPLY` that was more readable but had really poor performance. This is many times faster.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to create island groupings by

1. Calculating row number based on time (which is your `ID`)
2. Calculating row number for each distinct value
3. Grouping = (1) - (2)

Take a look at the example below:

```
declare @T table (ID int, BOUNDARY char(1), [TIMESTAMP] datetime2)
insert into @T values (1, null, '2016-01-01 00:20:00'), (2, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:20:10'), (3, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:20:14'), (4, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:20:22'), (5, null, '2016-01-01 00:20:38'), (6, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:20:45'), (7, 'B', '2016-01-01 00:21:02'), (8, 'B', '2016-01-01 00:21:12'), (9, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:21:16'), (10, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:21:22'), (11, 'C', '2016-01-01 00:21:30'), (12, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:21:35'), (13, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:21:40'), (14, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:21:46'), (15, 'A', '2016-01-01 00:21:50')

select 
    BOUNDARY, 
    min(ID) as [START ID], 
    max(id) as [END ID]
from
(
    select 
        ID, 
        BOUNDARY, 
        ID - 
        row_number() over (partition by BOUNDARY order by TIMESTAMP) as grp
    from @T as t
) as T
where BOUNDARY is not null
group by grp, BOUNDARY
having count(*) >= 2
order by min(ID)
```

Comment: +1 but I think the order by TIMESTAMP should really be ID especially if TIMESTAMPs could be out of order e.g. change record 3 to be 1 day later and you get a funky result.

Comment: @Aducci, thanks, but not quite.  I tried this above, and it groups all 'A' boundaries as one record, with start as 2 and end as 15.  In reality, I need 3 separate 'A' records in the above.  However, this is a start and something I might be able to work with.

Comment: @user3150002 - the script outputs the right results for me. Not sure what you are running?